# Does CDI work inside OSGI bundle (GF4, WELD)?

Tags: java, osgi, cdi, jboss-weld

Maybe this is a stupid question but I have a component class (it's used as service - declarative service) and I can't inject anything in it after several hours. 
What I do is

```
@Inject
InterfaceName name;
```

Is this my mistake or it's impossible?
At the same time I can inject this service into another bundle via `@Inject @OSGiService`.

I didn't get any compilation or deployment error. The only problem that the `name` field is `null` (`java.lang.NullPointerException`).

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Pax CDI](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXCDI/Pax+CDI), it is possible to use Injection also in OSGi. You are free to choose whatever injection framework you want to use, either weld, openwebbeans or deltaspike.